# Finding similar strings (same words in different order) in a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings:

```
 listA = [u'hour block', u'block hour', u'package hour', u'hour block hour']
```

I want to find all strings that are similar (i.e., from the above example `'hour block'` and `'block hour'`) and include only the string that occurred first from the two (i.e., `'hour block'` in this case), and the remaining strings occur in their order.

So, the output of the above should be:

```
[u'hour block', u'package hour', u'hour block hour']
```

I'm thinking in the following terms:

```
>>> for x in listA:
...     y = x.split()
```

But, I can't figure out how do I compare each word of the strings in the list optimally?

Comment: by simillar you mean exactly the SAME words, just different order? then use set....

Comment: You must define "similar" first.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done.

```
listB = [y.split() for y in listA]
listC = []
for i, l1 in enumerate(listB[::-1]):
   flag = 0
   for j, l2 in enumerate(listB[::-1][i + 1:]):
      if len(l1) == len(l2) and set(l1) == set(l2):
          flag = 1
          break
   if flag == 0: 
      listC.append(l1)

listC = [' '.join(c) for c in listC[::-1]]
print listC
```

Output:

```
[u'hour block', u'package hour', u'hour block hour']
```

Comment: @Arman Also a good solution. Just check if you want `block hour block` and `hour block hour` be similar or not.

Comment: @Y.Luo That's a good call out. I would definitely consider them to be similar as well.

Comment: @Arman You're better off handling these situations on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Shiva The problem is that your output is giving 'block hour' however in the question I mentioned that it should give out 'hour block', i.e., the similar string that occurred first.

Comment: @Arman My answer treat `block hour block` and `hour block hour` as different. I'll delete my answer. Sorry, I'm not clear about your "similarity".

Comment: @Arman I see the issue, and I've fixed it. Check my edit and output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` or `frozenset` for making unique items.  Try following

```
listA = [u'hour block', u'block hour', u'package hour', u'hour block hour']

sets = set()
unique = []

for item in listA:
    splitted = item.split()

    # Storing set of items(unique) and its count for comparision.
    # hour block and hour block hour gives same set, so length is required
    s = frozenset( { frozenset(item.split()), len(item.split()) } )
    if s not in sets:
        unique.append(item)
    sets.add(s)


print(unique)
```

Output `['hour block', 'package hour', 'hour block hour']`